# I need help fixing a script with the compiler error CS1002

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am having an issue with my incomplete shooting script. I tried testing it out, but I can't due to the error CS1002. If anyone has the solution to this issue, it would gradually help me out. You can read my code here:

The errors seem to be in line 27 and 28.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using StarterAssets;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private StarterAssetsInputs _input;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _input = transform.root.GetComponent<StarterAssetsInput>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (_input.shoot)
        {
            Shoot();
            _input.shoot = false;
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        Debug.log("shoot!")
    }
}
```

I tried to play the game and test it out to see if it was functioning, but I couldn't test it due to the error.

Comment: Error CS0117 might be related to it, just add the missing semicolon and see how that goes.

Comment: I added to semicolon and now i have 2 more errors: CS0117, debug does not contain definition for log, and CS0246, the type or namespace StarterAssetInput could not be found. Do you have any way to fix these for me? Sorry I'm asking for a lot.

Comment: Try it with `Debug.Log` (uppercase L).

Comment: Great, that worked! One last thing however, the error CS0246: The type or namespace name StarterAssetInput could not be found.

Comment: Use `StarterAssetsInputs` instead of `StarterAssetsInput`. Here: `GetComponent<StarterAssetsInputs>`

Comment: Where do I put GetComponent<StarterAssetsInputs>?

Comment: You have it already in the right place in the `Start()` function, just add an `s` to the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a semicolon missing here:

```
void Shoot()
{
    Debug.log("shoot!") ;
}
```

You need to end a C# statement with a semicolon, even if it's followed by a closing bracket.